# Is it a reception if a receiver hops twice on one foot?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

Assuming an NFL receiver catches a ball and maintains possession, if he hops twice on the same foot before going out of bounds, does it count as a catch?  Does the rule book specifically say it needs to be two distinct feet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NFL rule (8.1.3b) is written as "touches the ground inbounds with both feet or with any part of his body other than his hands;"

So you need both feet to touch inbounds, or one foot and and a knee, etc.

See [NFL rulebook online](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2018-nfl-rulebook/#article-3.-completed-or-intercepted-pass).

Comment: actually, the foot is not required if a knee touches.  Thus the John Madden book, One Knee Equals Two Feet